# Exclusão envolvendo Java e SQL

Tags: java, sql

O programa que estou fazendo necessita de uma exclusão de usuários do banco!

No código eu determino:

```
Menu:

static private void Excluir(Connection con) throws SQLException
{
    String cpf;
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    Cliente cli = new Cliente();

    System.out.println("Informe o CPF a ser Excluido:");
    cli.cpf = s.next();
    System.out.println();
    cli.ExcluirPess(cli, con);
}
```

Na classe cliente eu determino:

```
public void ExcluirPess(Cliente cli, Connection con) throws SQLException {
      String sql = "delete from Cliente where CPF_cliente = ?"; 
      PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);  
      stmt.setString(1, cli.getCpf());
      stmt.executeUpdate();
      stmt.close();
}
```

Arrumei conforme demonstraram, mas a exclusão ainda não é feita! O fato onde no banco a `PK CPF_cliente` ser `FK` em `Endereco` e `Telefone`, interfere na exclusão?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você deve adicionar o parâmetro e em seguida executar o seu PreparedStatement.

```
String sql = "delete from Cliente where CPF_cliente = ?"; 
PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);  
stmt.setString(1, cli.cpf);
stmt.executeUpdate();
```

> O fato onde no banco a PK CPF_cliente ser FK em Endereco e Telefone, interfere na exclusão?

Com certeza, o banco de dados não permite que você faça tal exclusão para não gerar uma inconsistência no banco de dados, pois senão as tabelas Endereco e Telefone teriam uma chave estrangeira que não existe na tabela Cliente.

Para consertar, apague primeiro os registros nas tabelas que possuem a chave estrangeira e em por último apague o registro na tabela Cliente.

Comment: Acho que ao invés de `cli.getCpf()` vai ser `cli.cpf`.

Comment: @Piovezan é possível, não dá para ter certeza pois o OP não mostrou a classe Cliente, entretanto cli.cpf é mais garantido que funcione. Mudei conforme sua sugestão.

Comment: @Math Obrigado, conforme você disse realmente é necessário excluir primeiramente as `FK` para depois excluir diretamente a `PK` table Cliente

Comment: @Bruno acredito que você tenha excluído através do preparedstatement, da mesma maneira que eu faria. Apenas a nível de informação, existe uma outra maneira de se fazer isso, seriam os `Stored Procedures`, que _automaticamente_ deleta as FKs do registro que você exclui, entretanto eu acabei não citando na resposta para não ficar muito longa e por que talvez não é interessante para você. Apenas saiba que existe essa outra opção, caso um dia se interesse.

Comment: @Math não sabia dessa outra maneira de exclusão dos `FKs`, pelo visto é uma opção bem mais fácil de se utilizar. Obrigado por adicionar essa outra opção.

Comment: @Bruno depois que se aprende a faze-los pode-se dizer que é mais fácil, entretanto dependendo do porte da sua aplicação vai optar por não ter que aprender um novo comando, tudo depende do que está buscando.

Comment: @Math entendo, como minha aplicação está envolvendo a faculdade, não seria bom encaixar o `Stored Procedures`. Mesmo assim é bom saber de outras maneiras para efetuar as exclusões, irá ajudar muito no mercado futuramente!

Comment: Na verdade nem precisa criar uma Stored Procedures 90% dos bandos de dados que conheço exite a opção Cascate on Delete, ou seja quando setamos a FK dizemos como ela reagir a exclusão e a modificação, as opções são ignorar, impedir ou cascata, na opção cascata você excluindo a FK todos os que tiverem ela como chave estrangeira também serão excluídos. <pre>FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES products (id)
       ON DELETE CASCADE
       ON UPDATE CASCADE,<code> Apenas um exemplo.